# 쓰다 + ㄴ 채 in use?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-usage, word-choice

Can somebody help me with the translation of this sentence:
그런데 좀 급하게 보내느라고 모임 장소도 안 쓴 채 보냈어요.

I further do not quite understand the use of ㄴ채 with 쓰다 in this case.

Comment: https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-5/lessons-109-116/lesson-116/

Comment: So the here means to "write".
장소도 안 쓴 = with not have written the place, either 
?

Comment: Yes, it means without the meeting place written on a letter or whatnot. The person was in a hurry so (s)he forgot to do something. The speaker did not write the meeting place in a paper (s)he just sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is mentioned in the comments, the translation would come out to be something along the lines of:

> I sent the letter without the meeting address on it because of my hurriedness.

The `~느라고` ending on `보내다` tells you that something negative will occur because of the following through of the verb (sending it hurriedly, `급하게 보내느라고`).

The `ㄴ 채` simply points more to the point that the speaker had not yet written the address the item being sent. `는/ㄴ 채(로)` is used to denote that something is in a certain state (in this case, it is the state of not having an address written on it, `모임 장소도 안 쓴 채`).